# Read a file containing unsigned ints and write it into binary in C++

Tags: c++, file, input

I have a text file containing unsigned integers in the range 0,..,2^32-1.
Each line contains a single integer (and a newline char).

I want to write it into a binary file to save space (such that each int will take exactly 4 bytes). What'd be the best way to do that?

I've tried a few options, none of them seems to work. Help will be appreciated.

Current (non working) code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int x;
    while (std::cin >> x){
        fwrite((void*)&x, sizeof(x), 1, stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It is compiled using:
`g++ compress.cc -o compress`.

However, it seems to only output the first integer.

For example, have the I ran the command `./compress < bla | wc -c`

Where "bla" is a file containing

```
1864754174
2150244390
1703231727
```

The result of the command was `4`, and not `12` as I expected.

Comment: What did you try? right now, this question is just give me the code. Which will be downvoted and closed almost immediately. Remember to edit your question, dont just answer this in the comments section.

Comment: @Ben - Added code, thanks for your comment.

Comment: Ok, now what doesn't work? Please read how to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Ben - it only writes the first integer and stops (the output file has exactly 4 bytes).

Comment: Edit, the question. You have asked enough questions on this site to know how to ask a good one.

Comment: The code looks OK (apart from the `return 1` - should be `return 0`, and the fact that `x` should be `uint32_t`, not `int`). You need to give a bit more detail about how you're building and running this and how it's not behaving as required,

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me.

Comment: Minimal is great, but methinks this is too minimal and doesn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Though personally I would have done: `std::cout.write((char*)&x, sizeof(x));`.

Comment: @Galik - is it a matter of style or performance choice?

Comment: @RB Mostly style I guess. It makes sense to me not to mix the `stdio` library calls with the `iostream` library calls. (they can be *unlinked* which could cause unexpected behavior in some situations).

Comment: If you care about performance then you could call `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);` before any other `IO` calls and then use my method for writing. You may find that helps because the internal system doesn't have to keep the `stdio` and `iostream` buffers synchronized.

Comment: @Galik - Thanks for the info ! What would be the right way then to read from the binary file without mixing the two?

Comment: I would do: `std::cin.read((char*)&i, sizeof(i))`.

Comment: @Galik - great, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is that you are trying to write int instead of unsigned int.
the diffrence between those 2 isnt the size of them but the use of the bytes.

in unsigned int every bit reprsent 2^(index -1) index starting from 1.

in int the bits are used like unsiged int just the last bit is used to reprsent the sign of the number and beacuse of that you can represent smaller numbers.

Comment: Does this explain why it seems to only write one `int`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to read from a text file containing uints and write those into a binary file. 
Reading:

```
std::vector<unsigned int> readUints(const std::string& filepath){
    std::vector<unsigned int> numbers;
    std::ifstream file(filepath);
    if(!file.is_open()){
        //Handle file not found
    }
    unsigned int number = 0;
    while(file >> number){
        numbers.push_back(number);
    }
    return numbers;
```

Writing:

```
void writeUints(const std::vector<unsigned int>& numbers, const std::string& filepath){
    std::ofstream file(filepath, ios_base::binary | ios_base::out);
    if(!file.is_open()){
        //Handle file not found
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&numbers[i], 4);
    }
}
```

Make sure to include `<fstream>`. You can change `unsigned int` to `uint32_t` to make sure it is exactly 32 bits wide on every platform